# Chrome Apps: Keep An App Visible + detect when not focused

Tags: focus, google-chrome-app, lost-focus

Keep an app visible:
I would like for an app to be visible when the user has clicked off (not the X, but they've moved to a different window), like chromeos's music player.

Detect when not focused:
Self-explanatory
Sadly, I can't give code samples because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Add the "alwaysOnTopWindows" permission to your manifest. Then create a window like this:

```
chrome.app.window.create("index.html", { alwaysOnTop: true })
```